# Проблема с обновлением свойства элемента в Битрикс

Tags: битрикс

Нужно пройтись по товарам и обновить свойство "SORT" у каждого элемента.

Реализация:

```
$arSelect = Array("ID", "SORT");
$arFilter = Array("IBLOCK_ID" => 2, "ACTIVE_DATE"=>"Y", "ACTIVE"=>"Y");
$res = CIBlockElement::GetList(Array(), $arFilter, false, Array(), $arSelect);
while($ob = $res->GetNextElement()) {
    $arFields = $ob->GetFields();
    $el = new CIBlockElement();
    $el->Update($arFields["ID"], array('SORT' => 100));
}
```

Все идет хорошо, но на определенном элементе скрипт падает, т.к. в описании данного элемента имеются символы, которые рвут строку (кавычки, что ли, но не суть):

```
FILE: /var/www/apteka.local/public/bitrix/modules/iblock/classes/mysql/iblockelement.php
LINE: 1532
MySQL Query Error: UPDATE b_iblock_element SET `SORT` = 100, `SEARCHABLE_CONTENT` = 'Оликлиномель N7-1000E эмул.д/инф.пакет трехкамерн.1500мл N4\r\nТрехкомпонентная смесь предназначена для...
```

Непонятно, почему так происходит, ведь я обновляю только одно свойство...

Как можно решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 0):

У вас проблема с поисковым контентом - данную проблему в текущей задаче вы можете решить при помощи дополнительного параметра в функции апдейта.

[Документация](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/classes/ciblockelement/update.php)

```
while($ob = $res->GetNextElement()) {
    $arFields = $ob->GetFields();
    $el = new CIBlockElement();
    $el->Update(
         $arFields["ID"], 
         array('SORT' => 100),
         false,
         false //отключаем индексацию
    );
}
```

Обратите внимание на 4 параметр в функции (bUpdateSearch) - он отвечает за переиндексацию элемента модулем поиска. Вы можете отключить эту функцию при обновлении в вашем кейсе, но все таки элемент стоит перепроверить на валидность, потому что при глобальной переиндексации оно так же упадет скорее всего.

Comment: К сожалению, упал на том же месте...